# Classification where the number of classes is huge

Tags: face-recognition, multilabel-classification, image-classification

I want to build a scalable face recognition system with many classes. I have access to at most 1 photo of each face with the person's name as a label. Now, I intend to take another photo of the person, and if it matches the face in the dataset, it should output the person's name.

How do I approach this problem? Can One-shot learning be of any help?